# JS how to render a template from a object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string template such as:

```
template = `<li>${name}<li><li>${address}<li><li>${sex}<li>`
```

I have defined a object {name: "tom", address: "usa", sex: "male"} in js file.

how can I render the template by the object directly?
to get result as:

```
<li>tom<li><li>usa<li><li>male<li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:)

```js
var obj = {name: "tom", address: "usa", sex: "male"};
var result;
with(obj)
    result = `<li>${name}<li><li>${address}<li><li>${sex}<li>`
```

or

```js
var obj = {name: "tom", address: "usa", sex: "male"};
var template = "<li>${name}<li><li>${address}<li><li>${sex}<li>";
var result = template.replace(/\${(\w+)}/g, function($0, $1) {
    return obj[$1];
});
```

Comment: [Warning: Use of the with statement is not recommended, as it may be the source of confusing bugs and compatibility issues. See the "Ambiguity Contra" paragraph in the "Description" section below for details.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with)

Comment: "with" statement match my expectation, it's cool, although it is still not recommended, and is forbidden in ECMAScript 5 strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use the template literal when you access the object

I also had to fix your HTML to close the LIs

```js
const arr = [
{ name: "tom", address: "usa", sex: "male" },
{ name: "lisa",address: "usa", sex: "female"}
];

document.getElementById('ul').innerHTML = arr
  .map(({ name, address, sex}) => `<li>${name}</li><li>${address}</li><li>${sex}</li>`)
  .join("")
```

```html
<ul id="ul"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `obj.` in the template and it should work.

```
var obj = {name: "tom", address: "usa", sex: "male"};
var template = `<li>${obj.name}<li><li>${obj.address}<li><li>${obj.sex}<li>`;
console.log(template);
// <li>tom<li><li>usa<li><li>male<li>
```

or you can destructure the object like so:

```
var obj = {name: "tom", address: "usa", sex: "male"};

// destructure
const { name, address, sex } = obj;

var template = `<li>${name}<li><li>${address}<li><li>${sex}<li>`;
console.log(template);
// <li>tom<li><li>usa<li><li>male<li>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a [tagged template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates)? Pass in your object to the template and have it render your HTML.

```js
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');

const obj = { name: 'tom', address: 'usa', sex: 'male' };

function details(strings, ...rest) {
  const [ name, address, sex ] = rest;
  return `<li>${name}</li><li>${address}</li><li>${sex}</li>`;
}

const output = details`${obj.name}${obj.address}${obj.sex}`;

ul.innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```